# Subfolder as Root with .htaccess - For use with Relative URLs of sub-sub-folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, relative-path

Here is my folder structure.  Currently when I go to my `subfolder`  all my relative links (in css and images, javascript, etc) link to the `Roots` direct subfolders.

I simply want all those to always utilize my `subfolder` as a root.

```
+ Root
-- .htaccess
-- images
-- js
-- css
-- subfolder
--+ .htaccess
--+ images
--+ js
--+ css
```

I have tried adding a few things to my `subfolders` `.htaccess` but nothing changes (I have verified that the .htaccess does indeed work).

**Doesnt work **

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /subfolder$1 [L]
....
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RedirectMatch ^/$ /subfolder/
RewriteOptions InheritDown
```

Comment: You should be using relative links to css, js instead of absolute linkes

Comment: @anubhava Of course I am already using Relative links in my css and js ?

Comment: When using relative links, if your current URL is `http://example.com/subfolder/anything` then it will access `http://example.com/subfolder/css/style.css`